# Multi Hop, Self Closing, Background SSH Tunnel

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, tunnel

I'm trying to create a multi hop ssh tunnel, that is in the background, and self closing.  What I have is...

```
ssh -L 9999:localhost:9999 user@host1 -t ssh -L 9999:localhost:27017 -N 
-i ./mypem.pem user@host2
```

This successfully creates a multi hop ssh tunnel that closes the port on host1 after I close the tunnel.  However, if I try to fork it to the background, like this...

```
ssh -f -L 9999:localhost:9999 user@host1 -t ssh -L 9999:localhost:27017 
-N  -i ./mypem.pem user@host2
```

It runs in the background, but killing the process locally does open the port back on host 1.

Any ideas for a self closing, multi hop, background ssh tunnel? Thanks!

Comment: does `-o "ExitOnForwardFailure yes"` work?

Comment: I gave this a shot:

`ssh -f -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -L 9999:localhost:9999 user@host1 ssh -L 9999:localhost:27017 -N -i ./mypem.pem user@host2`

But same issue, when I close the tunnel locally, 9999 on the host isn't open.  So if I try to reopen the tunnel, I get `bind: Address already in use`

Comment: Ok either try `-o "ClearAllForwardings yes"` or forward witn `ProxyCommand`and `-W`

Comment: Have you tried without `-N` and then appending a `sleep X` at the end. Something like: `ssh -f -L 9999:localhost:9999 user@host1 -t 'ssh -L 9999:localhost:27017 -i ./mypem.pem user@host2 "sleep 3600"'`

Comment: I'd switch to the ProxyCommand approach; it's way cleaner in a number of ways. See [serverfault: "How do I do Multihop SCP transfers?"](https://serverfault.com/questions/37629/how-do-i-do-multihop-scp-transfers) (the same thing works for plain SSH and port forwards) and [backdrift: "Using SSH ProxyCommand to Tunnel Connections"](https://backdrift.org/transparent-proxy-with-ssh).

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @iamauser - that did the trick! I'll admit that I don't fully understand how but it's certainly working.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For self-closing, one can use a simple `sleep X` command.

```
$ ssh -f -L 9999:localhost:9999 user@host1 \
-t 'ssh -L 9999:localhost:27017 -i ./mypem.pem user@host2 "sleep 3600"'
```

Note, this doesn't use the `-N` option, which is for *not* running a command, instead, we run a command `sleep 3600`. This keeps the tunnel up for 1 hour and closes itself after that.